# iOS data management

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, data-management

I'm writing a simple iOS App to manage Email address, maybe like Contacts. I don't know what is the best way to organize data in iOS and don't know which database that iOS and Xcode support. I just know that iOS supports XML & SQLite, are there other databases supported?

Which is the best database (XML, SQLite,...) for this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to add only email and contacts then my suggestion is you just use plist.

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html

Comment: +1 Simple and quick. Just a simple `NSArray`. It also has methods for saving to and reading from a plist.

Answer (score 0):

You should try CoreData. Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to see what's it about. It offers a great way to handle the things you said you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is good option. The persistence used by core data is abstracted away while you can still choose SQLite, XML, or in memory for the persistent store.